# Django filtering from other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

For example I have two models:

```
class Symbol(models.Model):
    rowID = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=true)

class SymbolProperties(models.Model):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol, to_field='rowID', db_column='symbol')
    some_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And I want to filter `Symbol` objects with `some_value` field, but model Symbol have no relation to SymbolProperties.
Can I do it without creating foreign key in Symbol model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. When you declare a `ForeignKey` on one model, a reverse relationship is added to the other one (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)).

You can access the related field as an attribute (`symbol.symbolproperties_set`, or whatever name you define using the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) keyword argument in the model field definition) or reference it in a lookup:

```
Symbol.objects.filter(symbolproperties__some_value=5)
```

(Add `distinct()` to ensure that the result only contains unique instances of `Symbol`.)

Comment: Wouldn't this code result in an error? `symbolproperty_set` won't resolve to a field on the Symbol class...

Comment: @Brandon: I've edited the answer with more details (and corrected the filter lookup). This works because Django creates the related field attribute for you.

Comment: Ah. I forgot that `related_name` can also be referenced as a field.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to objects from either side of a relationship. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward for more information.

Try:

```
symbols = SymbolProperties.objects.filter(some_value=the_value).only('symbol')
```

This may result in duplicate `symbol` instances in the returned QuerySet. To get rid of those, you'd need to create a `set` of the results.